# Two overlapping list: plot odd and even from each in different colors

Tags: plotting

I have two lists produce by a script that are most likely identical (but might not be).

I would like to plot them using `ListPlot[]` in such a way to display only even elements from the first list and odd elements from the second one, essentially interleaving the two lists. Goal is to show that the two are in fact overlapping.

Sample data is just two identical lists such as

```
a = Table[y,{y,1,20}];
b = Table[y,{y,1,20}];
```

My lists come without x coordinates but can be added if needed.

Comment: Can you post example data...?

Comment: `ListPlot[{list1[[;; ;; 2]], list2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sample data which actually is identical, of the form `{x, y}`, you can do this with creative use of [Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
data1 = data2 = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, .1}];

ListPlot[{data1[[1 ;; ;; 2]], data2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

`data1[[1 ;; ;; 2]]` takes every 2nd element of `data1` starting from element 1, `data2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]` takes every 2nd element of `data2` starting from element 2.

Specifying `PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}` isn't explicitly necessary as they sets of data will be different styles by default, but you may wish to control how they look.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
l = RandomReal[100, 30];
{list1, list2} = Thread[{Range[30], #}] & /@ ({#, # + RandomReal[{-.05, 05}]} & @ l);

ListPlot[{list1[[;; ;; 2]], list2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"list1", "list2"}, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]